# How to fix repeating function ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a function wpb_nos_formules() which makes an show répéteur field . How can fix this function?
I don't know where the error is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQoz6.png)

```
function wpb_nos_formules() 
  {
    if( have_rows('formule') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('formule') ): the_row(); 
     // vars
     $title = get_sub_field("title");
    ?>
           <ul>
           <li><?php echo $title; ?></li>
           </ul>

     <?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); 
         // vars
         $titlee = get_sub_field("title");
         $description = get_sub_field("description");
      ?>
    <ul>
      <li><?php echo $titlee; ?></li>
      <li><?php echo $description; ?></li>
     </ul>
    <?php endwhile; 
   endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
            

 <?php endif; 
 }
 add_shortcode('latest_nos_formule', 'wpb_nos_formules');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised your code. Shortcode function should return. and also do not start `<?php` and close `?>` multiple times unless not needed.

```
function wpb_nos_formules(){

    $html = '';

    if( have_rows('formule') ) : while( have_rows('formule') ) : the_row(); 
        $title = get_sub_field("title");
        $html .='<ul>
                    <li>'.$title.'</li>
                </ul>';
        if( have_rows('slider') ) : while( have_rows('slider') ) : the_row(); 
            $titlee      = get_sub_field("title");
            $description = get_sub_field("description"); 
            $html .='<ul>
                        <li>'.$titlee.'</li>
                        <li>'.$description.'</li>
                    </ul>';
        endwhile; endif; 
        
    endwhile; endif;

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'latest_nos_formule', 'wpb_nos_formules' );
```

Comment: While this may answer the question....what did you actually fix? Posting a block of code without explanation is not overly helpful.